# Configuration of claims provider for application group or relying party

Tags: adfs, claims-based-identity, windows-server-2016

I have a Windows Server 2016 on which I am using ADFS. I followed the link at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-to-authenticate-users-stored-in-ldap-directories to configure LDAP (AD LDS) as claims provider trust. Next thing I wanted to configure the application groups or relying parties to use a specific claims provider. For example, I want to use AD for a application, LDS for another and both for third. Currently I get both the options for all the applications. Can anyone help managing this part?

My best guess is adding Issuance tranform rule --> Transform incoming claim because I have already checked access control policies and Properties for the relying party and application groups, and I did not find anything where I can mention the used claims provider trust or authentication method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to set up specific claims provider per relying party or application by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/home-realm-discovery-customization) document on home realm discovery customization. Below are the Powershell script to achieve this.

**For Relying Party (Ws-Fed)**

```
Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName "RP Name" -ClaimsProviderName @("Provider 1","Active Directory")
```

**For Application (SAML)**

```
Set-AdfsWebApiApplication -TargetName "Web App Name" -ClaimsProviderName @("Provider 1","Active Directory")
```

Here you provide the name of your relying party or application after `-TargetName` and List of claims provider names inside parantheses

Thing to note here is you are not setting claims provider for application group but individual applications inside that group, so use the names accordingly.