# How do I specify Claims provider for web application in AD-FS

Tags: openid-connect, adfs

I have been following the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53703658/configuration-of-claims-provider-for-application-group-or-relying-party) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/home-realm-discovery-customization) but whenever I do an OIDC authentication request the ADFS login page shows a list of Claims Providers.  I am unable to work out how to specify that, for this application, only one is relevant.  Set-AdfsWebApiApplication seemed to be the answer but I have run it to map the claims provider to the application to no avail.

Any suggestions of things I may have overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

•   If the claims provider for your web application using OIDC for authentication is Active directory, then you can follow the below steps to add it as a claims provider: -

1. On the server running AD FS, start AD FS Management.
2. In the Navigation Pane, expand Trust Relationships, and then select Claims Provider Trusts.
3. Under Claims Provider Trusts, right-click Active Directory, and then select Edit Claims Rules.
4. In the Rules Editor, select Add Rule.
5. In the Claim rule template list, select the Send LDAP Attributes as Claims template, and then select Next.
6. Create the following rule:
   a.  Claim rule name: UPN Claim Rule (or something descriptive)
   b.  Add the following mapping:
   c.  Attribute store: Active Directory
   d.  LDAP Attribute: User Principal Name OR any other attribute that you want to pass it as a claim for authentication
   e.  Outgoing Claim Type: UPN (attribute name according to ADSI)
7. Select Finish, and then select OK to close the Rules Editor.

•   Or else, if your IdP provider for claim authentication is other than Active Directory, then you can also try adding it manually through ADFS management console as below: -

1. Expand Trust Relationships node, right click Claims provider trust and select add claims provider trust.
2. Click Start at the welcome screen, then at the select data source workspace, select enter claims provider trust data manually.
3. Enter a value at the box for Specify Display Name and click Next.
4. Select the ADFS profile at the Choose profile dialog box.
5. At the configure URL dialog box, select ‘Enable support for the WS-Federation Passive Protocol’ and for the URL dialog box, enter the URL of the STS or your web app that will request a token.
6. At the configure identifier box, leave the default value which is the URL of your web app that you entered earlier.
7. Then at the Configure Certificates option, select the certificate used while configuring ADFS in the server, i.e., the SSL certificate that will be used for signing purposes.
8. At the Finish window, leave the checkbox selected and click Close.

•   Once the above steps are completed, then the Claim transformation dialog pane will open where you need to configure the claims transformation rules and attributes that need to pass for authentication. Also, ensure that the web application for which you are configuring the ADFS IdP authentication has SSL certificate installed from a trusted CA.

Thus, these are some of the ways through which also you can try adding a specific claims provider for your Web app relying party trust in ADFS.

Please refer the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/deploy/configure-the-ad-fs-server-for-claims-based-authentication?view=op-9-1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/troubleshooting/ad-fs-tshoot-claims-rules